# IE adding mass amount of blank space after floated images

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer

I'm doing some customizations to a shopify theme for a client, and I've included a simple snippet that is just a grid of three images with a description beneath each one.  The containing div of each image/description set is floated.

It renders perfectly fine on every browser except IE, which is adding some several hundred pixels of space beneath the grid.  When I comment out the images, and leave everything else, the space disappears. I've tried all sorts of things, and am really at a loss on this one.

Here's my code (I took out img src and hrefs to keep it clean):

```
<style>
.homePageGrid {
  margin-top: 125px;
  margin-bottom: 125px;
}

.homePageImageGrid {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

.homePageImageGrid img {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="homePageGrid">

<div class="homePageImageGrid">
    <img src = "#" width = "100%">
    <div class = "homePageImageLinkBox">
        <a href="" class="post-title">Cook with xx</a>
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="homePageImageGrid">
    <img src = "#" width = "100%">
    <div class = "homePageImageLinkBox">
        <a href="" class="post-title">Shop with xx</a>
    </div>               
</div>

<div class="homePageImageGrid">
    <img src = "#" width = "100%">
    <div class = "homePageImageLinkBox">
        <a href="" class="post-title">Give with xx</a>
    </div>              
</div>

<div style = "clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using `float`, so you need to clear `floating` as well. just add `overflow:hidden` for parent elements.

Comment: Thanks Kheema - unfortunately, the float is cleared and overflow:hidden on the parent elements didn't help.  Just an IE problem :(

Comment: Is it possible to make a fiddle?

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyLhjdfg/)

Comment: for me its works in IE11

Comment: Here's the actual link - does it work live? [live site](http://monte-bene.myshopify.com)

Comment: got the problem, the strange thing is if you remove the property `display:flex` from the body. After that huge vertical space removed.

Comment: If  you want I can add as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've inspected the website HTML Code and find out why there is huge vertical space. Its happened because in `body` element `display:flex` property are added which I don't think is required there.

Remove `display:flex` property from the body element and it will perfectly work in IE as well.